# Why can't I vote down a poor answer to my question?

Tags: support

Something is wrong when people acquire 14000 reputation posting untested suggestions that don't work, while those who have enough sense to know the limits of their knowledge have zero reputation.

Comment: A constructive idea here is to comment on the answer that it didn't work. And upvote the ones that do!

Comment: High reputation users who post bad answers are the exception, not the norm. The privilege to downvote requires very low reputation, it's easy to achieve, and so there is a very good chance that bad answers *will get downvoted*, regardless of who posted them.

Comment: How do you know the solution was untested? It happens often that a solution that works great for one person, doesn't work for another.

Comment: Pretty salty for someone asking others to help him.

Comment: THelper, I believe that the solution was untested because of Frank's use of the phrase "you can try". If he had tested it, I believe he would have written: "change the user the task runs under to your account".

Comment: @Won't: I'm sorry if my tone offends you, but people who bluster like they know more than they do are a pet peeve of mine; all the more so since the last election. And I asked the question for the benefit of all Windows 10 users. I already implemented a temporary workaround by renaming MusNotification.exe.

Comment: I'm not offended, don't worry. Just pointing out that your slip is showing. Good day to you, sir.

Answer (score 13):

Having plausibly found the [question in question](https://superuser.com/questions/1277314/how-can-i-change-properties-for-the-reboot-task) (it's the only question under your account), you need a minimum of [125 reputation](https://superuser.com/help/privileges) to vote down. Even then, you can only vote on questions and answers.

You can't downvote [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1277314/how-can-i-change-properties-for-the-reboot-task#comment1885705_1277314) because its a comment. It's kind of meant for clarification or for information that will not quite fit in an answer. You could flag it, but it seems premature, since it's still useful.

I suspect a good read of the tour and help may be in order at this point (Just for full disclosure — I couldn't find the reputation minimum for votes either, so I read through parts of it for this post)